# cmake dependency problem

Tags: cmake

I have 3 small dependent tools:

```
main-tool/
    tool1/
    tool2/ 

       * ----- main-tool ----- *
       |                       |
      tool1   ---------- >    tool2
```

The main-tool depends on tool1 & tool2.
The tool1 depends on tool2.
The CMakeFiles look like that:

```
main-tool/CMakeLists.txt
   SUBDIRS{"tool1"}
   SUBDIRS{"tool2"}

main-tool/tool1/CMakeLists.txt
   SUBDIRS("../tool2"}
```

I can compile tool1 smoothly. However whenever I want to compile main-tool the tool2 is included twice and produces error. How can I avoid this?

Thanks.

Comment: I solved this by setting up an VAR in main-tool/CMakeLists.txt and then by IF statements in tool1/CMakeLists.txt: IF (NOT DEFINED VAR) SUBDIR(../tool2) ENDIF (NOT DEFINED VAR). It works but it's obscure.

Comment: Maybe you should close the question if you already found a solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, you should use `add_subdirectory()` instead of `subdirs()`, which is [deprecated](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2007-August/015739.html).  You get more precise control of the order of processing that way.

Second, because everything depends on tool2, you should build tool2 first.

```
main-tool/CMakeLists.txt:
   add_subdirectory{"tool2"}
   add_subdirectory{"tool1"}
```

Don't add another `add_subdirectory` command in the tool1 directory.  There are two approaches you can use to access tool2 from the tool1 build.

1. First, you could define some cmake variables in the top level main CMakeLists.txt related to tool2, then populate those variables in the tool2 build.  You might need to use the PARENT_SCOPE directive to `set` those variables from the tool2 subdirectory.  Then use those variables to access tool2 from the tool1 subdirectory.
2. Alternatively, you could build all three tools (tool2, tool1, and main tool, in that order) from the top level CMakeLists file.  The build file can get long, but it saves headaches trying to manage the scope of cmake variables.  This is the approach I usually take and I recommend it.

To summarize, my recommendation is "one big CMakeLists.txt file".  Unless it gets really, really big.

Comment: Thanks Christopher, I went with the (1) and used the configure_file(). I didn't know about the PARENT_SCOPE. That would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You really should use `SUBDIRS` only for sub directories. What you actually mean by dependency? If you link some libraries together use `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES`, CMake will find them in your project regardless directory. If it is run time dependency, you usually care about it only after installation or you can use `"${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/../tool2/tool2"` as path to the binary.